# My function to find the max profit with k transactions returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function, output

I wrote a function to find the max profit from exactly k transactions, a transaction consist of buying at a low price and selling at a higher price 'you cannot buy and sell on the same day and must finish one transaction before another' for example given [ 100, 180, 260, 310, 40, 535, 695 ], 2 should return 865
Buy on day : 0   Sell on day: 3 Buy on day : 4   Sell on day: 6, total buy = 140, total sell = 105, max profit = 865 I have written a function for this but it returns an empty array

```
   function maxProfit(price, k) {
     // check for the availability of at least two prices and 1 transaction
     if ((k = 0 || price.length < 1)) return 0;

     // Initialize the profit;
     let profit = [];

     //Create count for each cycle of transaction
     for (let t = 1; t <= k; t++) {
       for (let i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
         // Find the day's Minimal by comparing present element to the next element
         if (price[i + 1] <= price[i]) i++;
         // When you find the first minimal then Find another day's Maximal
         else
           for (let j = i + 1; j <= price.length; j++) {
             // The day you find a higher price than you bought is the day at which the stock should be sold
             if (price[j] > price[i]) {
               let curr_profit = price[j] - price[i] + maxProfit(price, t + 1);

               // Update the maximum profit so far
               profit = Math.max(profit, curr_profit);
             }
           }
       }
     }
     // Update the profit so far
     return profit;
   }
```

```
//This is returning an empty array and I can't figure out why
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Comment: You never update the `profit` array. You only ever potentially override the variable but never add anything to the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

In line 2 (If statement), instead of an equal operator, you have used the assignment operator.

As k = 0, execution never get into the for loop "**for (let t = 1; t <= k; t++)**"

```
 if ((k = 0 || price.length < 1)) return 0; // old
 if ((k == 0 || price.length < 1)) return 0; // new
```

Also, it's better to remove the tail call recursion for better optimization.

```
let curr_profit = price[j] - price[i] + maxProfit(price, t + 1);
```

Comment: Oops, thank you, now it is returning an array but it is the wrong answer, it returns 595 instead of 865, meaning it executes just ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function maxProfit(price, k) { 

   // check for the availability of at least two prices and 1 transaction
    if (k = 0 || price.length < 1) 
        return 0; 

   // Initialize the profit;
    let profit =0;

   //Create count for each cycle of transaction
    for (let t = 1; t <= k; t++) {

        for (let i = 0; i < price.length; i++) { 

            // Find the day's Minimal by comparing present element to the next element
            if (price[i + 1] <= price[i])
                    i++
            else
                // When you find the first minimal then Find another day's Maximal
                for (let j = i + 1; j <= price.length; j++) { 

                    // The day you find a higher price than you bought is the day at which the stock should be sold
                    if (price[j] > price[i]) {

                        let curr_profit = price[j] - price[i] + maxProfit(price, t+1);

                        // Update the maximum profit so far
                        profit = Math.max(profit, curr_profit);   
                    } 
                }

        }

   }
    let profitArr = [profit];
       // Update the profit so far
       return profitArr
   }
```

It's nothing but storing the profit value as array because you never performed any action on the array